# Does Changing boot order sequence affect the existing OS?

Tags: operating-systems

I was hoping to boot another OS on my PC using a USB drive and I read that I should change the boot order sequence. If I do so, will my existing OS will be formatted and replaced?

Comment: Boot order will not affect anything other than boot order.

Comment: The only reason for changing the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot order would be if the USB will remain attached to the PC most of the time, otherwise use the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot menu. _(reasoning: the BIOS/UEFI firmware will generally remove USB from boot option #1 once a bootable USB isn't detected at boot and the BIOS/UEFI firmware will generally not re-add USB back to boot option #1 upon being detected after it previously wasn't - e.g. this scenario makes it a waste of time to change the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot order unless the USB will remain plugged in to the PC)_

Answer (score 0):

There are two way, in most BIOS/UEFI implementations, to change *boot order*.

- If you open BIOS configuration (e.g., pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on some PC's and holding it while powering on), then change the boot order so that USB comes first, then each time the PC boots, it will search first for USB, and if a bootable USB device is not present, it would select the next in order, e.g. the SSD or HDD.
- If you press the temporary boot order change key (e.g., pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> on some PC's and holding it while powering on), then any change to the boot order is temporary. The next time you reboot, it will start with the normal boot device, such as SSD or HDD.

Normally, booting from a USB device will change *nothing* on the SSD or HDD, **unless you save changes, such as permanently installing Linux.** That said, it is a **very good idea to make a complete disk image** before making changes that affect the OS. There are many free tools to make an image, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or these [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

Note that to run from USB, Windows may require the PC be booted without [Fast Startup](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/fast-startup-on-windows-11.html), and Fast Boot should be turned off in BIOS. There may be other BIOS changes needed as well, though I find Secure Boot can be left active for most bootable USB devices I've made.